# Matlab Elman Neural Network Testing Check From Training Data

Tags: matlab, neural-network, statistics, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am using 1. Training Input Data 2. Training Output Data and 3. Testing Input Data to get Testing Output Data using the following MATLAB Code.

```
clear all;
clc;
TRIN = xlsread('X.xlsx',1); %To read Training Input Data
TRO = xlsread('X.xlsx',2); %To read Training Output Data
TEIN = xlsread('X.xlsx',3); %To read Testing Input Data
X = con2seq(TRIN); %Convert to cell
T = con2seq(TEIN); %Convert to cell
Xs = con2seq(TRO); %Convert to cell
net = elmannet(1:2,10); %Default Values for layer delays and hidden sizes
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,X,T);%Training the system using the data
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
view(net)
TEO = net(Xs,Xi,Ai); %The required testing output
perf = perform(net,Ts,TEO)
```

Though I am using

```
388 x 192 Training Input Data
388 x 48 Training Output Data and
31 x 192 Testing Input Data
```

I am getting 31 x 190 Testing Output Data instead of 31 x 48 Output Data. How can I proceed from here.

Comment: `Xs` is overwritten before used. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @Yvon Since TRO is the input of testing data, I overwrote the Xs Value. If I use it as another term, it does not get involved in the whole training process